# how can i get date from many to many table for gridview?

Tags: gridview, yii2

model:

```
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Groups::className(), ['id' => 'employee_id'])
            ->viaTable('groups_of_employee', ['group_id' => 'id']);
}
```

view:

```
<div class="site-index">
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $provider,
'columns' => [
    'lastname',
    'position',
    'groups.name_of_group'
   ],
 ]);  
 ?>
```

I've written this code it works without errors but fields name_of_group is empty. where is the bug located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't able to just pass the relation and then the table name/class property if the relation is many to many.  It doesn't inherently know how to output multiple results in one column so you will need to do something similar to this...

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'columns' => [
        'lastname',
        'position',
        [
            'label' => 'Groups'
            'value' => function($data) {
                $names = '';
                foreach ($data->groups as $group) {
                    $names .= $group->name_of_group . ', ';
                }
                return $names;
            },
        ]
    ],
]);  
?>
```

This will get you started but you will probably want to apply some different formatting for listing all the names, such as a HTML list.